# Open Search, exclude field from indexing in mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I have the following mapping:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "type": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "body": {
      "type": "text"
    },
    "id": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "date": {
     "type": "date"
    },
  },
}
```

body field is going to be an email message, it's very long and I don't want to index it.

what is the proper way to exclude this field from indexing?

What I tried:

`enabled: false` - as I understand from the documentation, it's applied only to `object` type fields but in my case it's not really an object so I'm not sure whether I can use it.

`index: false/'no'` - this breaks the code at all and does not allow me to make a search. My query contains query itself and aggregations with filter. Filter contains range:

```
date: { gte: someDay.getTime(), lte: 'now' }
```

P.S. someDay is a certain day in my case.

The error I get after applying index: false in mapping to the body field is the following:

```
{
    "error":
    {
        "root_cause":
        [
            {
                "type": "number_format_exception",
                "reason": "For input string: \"now\""
            }
        ],
        "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
        "reason": "all shards failed",
        "phase": "query",
        "grouped": true,
        "failed_shards":
        [
            {
                "shard": 0,
                "index": "test",
                "node": "eehPq21jQsmkotVOqQEMeA",
                "reason":
                {
                    "type": "number_format_exception",
                    "reason": "For input string: \"now\""
                }
            }
        ],
        "caused_by":
        {
            "type": "number_format_exception",
            "reason": "For input string: \"now\"",
            "caused_by":
            {
                "type": "number_format_exception",
                "reason": "For input string: \"now\""
            }
        }
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

I'm not sure how these cases are associated as the error is about `date` field while I'm adding index property to `body` field.

I'm using: `"@opensearch-project/opensearch": "^1.0.2"`

Please help me to understand:

1. how to exclude field from indexing.
2. why applying index: false to `body` field in mapping breaks the code an I get an error associated with `date` field.

Comment: Can you show the command you run to apply `index:false` to your `body` field?

Comment: @Val, thank you for your question. It's a rest call, which I do like this: `.put(this.name, {
      mappings: this.mappings,
    })
`
It works fine

Comment: Ok, then can you show the mapping resulting from this call?

Comment: since I made body to to be object type and enabled: false in the mapping, after this call I get the following mapping:

```{
  "body": {
    "type": "object",
    "enabled": false
  },
  "id": {
    "type": "keyword"
  },
  "date": {
    "type": "date"
  },
}```

Comment: `body` cannot be of type `object` since it's supposed to contain text... you need to keep `text` and use `index: false` instead

Comment: indeed, it's working now. with type: object it's not working. open search documentations is not really obvious, it doesn't have anything about index parameter at all. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just modify your mapping to this:

```
"body": {
   "type": "text",
   "index": false
}
```

And it should work